# Hector_slam and robot_localization

Tags: slam, navigation, hokuyo-node, 2d-mapping, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to fuse my hokuyo urg laser scan with my IMU data and use in hector_slam.
Currently hector_slam takes in the hokuyo laser scan data and outputs it to /poseupdate then I combine
that with my IMU data using robot_localization where I get a odometry/filtered that is the combination of both. But I don't know how to get it back into hector_slam to be able to get a more precesise positon.
How would I go about puting it back to hector_slam?
Am I doing this wrong?

Ros noob,

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226978/hector_slam--and-robot_localization/) by [bote795](https://answers.ros.org/users/25980/bote795/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure what you mean by getting the combination back into hector_slam. What exactly would you expect the result to be?

As far as I know the only way to give prior information into hector slam is via TF, and even then, it only serves as a starting point for the scan-to-map matching, meaning that there is no probabilistic fusion between the prior and the information of the laser scan matching.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2016-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1